# Maximizing cross entropy reinforcement learning

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, reinforcement-learning

I have read that in reinforcement learning, maximizing the entropy enables the policy to behave more randomly. My question comes in three parts:

(1) In the equation below in the cross-entropy term what does the dot • symbol stand for?

[image]

(2) if maximizing the entropy also makes the policy behave more randomly - then does that mean that it prevents training an optimum policy to convergence?

(3) [I have seen entropy being implemented as](https://github.com/BoYanSTKO/Practical_RL-coursera/blob/master/week5_policy_based/practice_reinforce.ipynb)

```
entropy = -tf.reduce_sum(policy * log_policy, 1, name="entropy")
```

However the policy is the output of the softmax **and not the actual label as is usually the case for cross entropy**. Is there a reason why the label (0 for move left, or 1 for move right) was not used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. expr$(\cdot)$ is shorthand for a function which takes as input $x$ and returns expr$(x)$. The distinction here is between expr$(x)$ -- an output of the function -- and expr$(\cdot)$ which is the function itself.
2. This depends on the exact algorithm. An off-policy RL algorithm can converge to the optimal solution even if the rollout policy is not optimal. For on-policy algorithms, $\alpha$ is generally small enough that it's not a concern. $\alpha$ can also be annealed to 0 over time.
3. Entropy is a functional of probability distributions, such as $\pi(\cdot|s)$. A sample from a probability distribution doesn't have entropy.

Comment: I noticed that you are very knowledgeable in reinforcement learning : I made a new post with a different question - I would be grateful if you could look at it : https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/369484/multi-agent-actor-critic-maddpg-algorithm-confusion